# What is Swift alternative to NSRange.location and NSRange.length?

Tags: swift, objective-c, string, nsrange

I am trying the find some alternative to `NSRange.location` and `NSRange.length` in Swift.

I have a string for example `sip:name@xyz.com`

I am trying to extract name from it. I can do it using `componentsSeperatedBy` method from String. But I was wondering whether it can be done using range similar to Objective C.

I already have old legacy Objective C code which I am trying to convert to Swift.

```
// Extract name from sip:name@xyz.com.....
NSString *name = nil;
NSRange rangeForSip;
NSRange rangeFor@;
rangeForSip = [self rangeOfString: @"sip:"];

if (rangeForSip.location  == NSNotFound) {
    //Look for sips
    rangeForSip = [self rangeOfString: @"sips:"];
}
  match2 = [self rangeOfString: @"@"];

if ((rangeForSip.location != NSNotFound) && (rangeFor@.location != NSNotFound)) {
    name = [self substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeForSip.location + rangeForSip.length, rangeFor@.location - (rangeForSip.location + rangeForSip.length))];
} else if (rangeFor@.location != NSNotFound) {
    // Extract name from sip:name@xyz.com.....
    name = [self substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, rangeFor@.location)];
}
```

Comment: A *free translation* of the code can take advantage of Swift Regex  in a String extension: `let name = self.firstMatch(of: /(?:sips?:)?([^@]+)@/)?.output.1`. The result is of type `Substring?`

Comment: Don't convert old legacy Objective-C code. Ask how to extract the name in Swift.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the `range` method in `NSString`, Swift `Strings` also have a [`range`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/range(of:options:range:locale:)) method that finds a particular substring in a string.

You can create your desired range by using the `..<` operator on the `lowerBound` and `upperBound` of the found ranges of "sip:" and "@".

You can then pass the range to the `String` subscript to get the result as a `Substring`.

If I understand correctly, the logic you want is:

```
func parseNameFrom(_ string: String) -> Substring? {
    let rangeOfSip = string.range(of: "sip:") ?? string.range(of: "sips:")
    if let rangeOfAt = string.range(of: "@") {
        if let rangeOfSip {
            return string[rangeOfSip.upperBound..<rangeOfAt.lowerBound]
        } else {
            return string[..<rangeOfAt.lowerBound]
        }
    } else {
        return nil // can't find it
    }
}

print(parseNameFrom("sip:name@xyz.com")!)
```

Comment: Hey Sweeper, just some minor suggestions: Some guard-lets can help unnest some of this code., 2) Once all the parsing is done, it might be best to promote back into a `String`